# Keep getting [MonoDroid] Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError' was thrown. In Release mode

Tags: java, android, xamarin

If I run my application in debug mode everything works fine.
If I build it in release mode it runs with 0 errors but as soon as I start the application I get the following error in release mode

[MonoDroid] Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError' was thrown.

How can I fix this?
Here is my output

```
 [monodroid] Trying to load sgen   from: /data/data/payment24_Mobile.payment24_Mobile/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
    [monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
    [Notificare] Launching Notificare
    [MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
    [MonoDroid] Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception of    type 'Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError' was thrown.
    [MonoDroid] at   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw   () <0x00028>
    [MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod   (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) <0x000e7>
     [MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x001cb>
     [MonoDroid] at Payment24_Mobile.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle)  <0x00027>
     [MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_     (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
     [MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.9bf92fe1-7a19-4e78-bb84-  935c3dfa8604 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
     [MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
     [MonoDroid] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
     [MonoDroid]    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
     [MonoDroid]    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
     [MonoDroid]    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
    [MonoDroid]     at md5527bbe1570afed42e60989b1b5cbd5aa.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
   [MonoDroid]  at md5527bbe1570afed42e60989b1b5cbd5aa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
   [MonoDroid]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
   [MonoDroid]  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
   [MonoDroid]  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
     [MonoDroid]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     [MonoDroid]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    [MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    [MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    [MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    [MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    [MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   [AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
  [AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   [AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
   [AndroidRuntime]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
     [AndroidRuntime]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
     [AndroidRuntime]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at md5527bbe1570afed42e60989b1b5cbd5aa.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
   [AndroidRuntime]     at md5527bbe1570afed42e60989b1b5cbd5aa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
   [AndroidRuntime]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
   [AndroidRuntime]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
   [AndroidRuntime]     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1218)
   [AndroidRuntime]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     [AndroidRuntime]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   [AndroidRuntime]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
     [AndroidRuntime]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: are you using any library and Appcompat?

Comment: yes I am using appCompat for my theme of my app

Comment: Please import  appCompat as project in your app project.

Comment: and also add your MainActivity class in which you are getting error

Comment: Hi do you have an example I can follow? I just started working with it so still very new. Should u add my style? I got it from a example online not sure if that could be the problem or not

Comment: please have a look of my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
what are the steps for that? where is AppCompat located?
```

Download the support library here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

If you are using Eclipse:

Go to the tabs at the top and select ( Windows -> Android SDK Manager ). Under the 'extras' section, check 'Android Support Library' and check it for installation.

[image]

After that, the AppCompat library can be found at:

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

You need to reference this AppCompat library in your Android project.

Import the library into Eclipse.

Right click on your Android project.

Select properties.

Click 'add...' at the bottom to add a library.

Select the support library

Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I am using xamarin and I have updated  the android support libary